# SVJour3 template and table's font size

Tags: tables, fontsize, sv-classes

I have a document composed with `svjour3` template.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
```

And I am trying to apply different font size for my table as it is very huge and does not fit into the page. I have tried different approaches, but table's font size remains the same (as all text in the paper):

I have tried `{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont`

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{...
...
\end{tabular}
}
```

I have tried `\small`

```
\begin{table}[]
...
\small
\begin{tabular}{...
...
\end{tabular}
```

I have tried `\footnotesize` as well. Nothing helps.

Does it mean that Springer's article template restricts font adjustment for tables?

Comment: Idk, whether Springer's template restricts it, but you should look into Springer's guidelines on font sizes, whether they want you to change font sizes in tables. If it doesn't work easily they usually don't want to.

Comment: I can't believe in it, as there are various situations where data in a table can be quite huge and it does not fit into the page. Obviously I can always paste it as image, but it is an ugly option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments:

- The default relative font size used by the `svjour3` document class for `table` environments is `\small`. Hence, typing `\small` explicitly inside a `table` environment won't achieve anything.
- The document class (specifically: the auxiliary file `svglov3.clo`, which is loaded by `svjour3.cls`) also features the instruction `\let\footnotesize\small`. Hence, typing `\footnotesize` inside a `table` environment won't change the font size either.
- To really reduce the size of the `tabular` material, then, try issuing the commands `\scriptsize` or (drum roll) `\tiny`.
- If you do this, you should also reduce the value of `\tabcolsep`, which is the length parameter that governs the amount of inter-column whitespace. Its default value is `6pt`. Try either `\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}` or `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` and decide if you like the result.

Comment: @Andremoniy - You're most welcome!